# Alfresco :: how to transfer a file from one server to alfresco repository

Tags: rest, alfresco, file-transfer

I have few files in my Apache web server. 
Now I want to move those files into alfresco repository.

I am looking for alfresco REST API to move those files from Apache web server into alfresco repository. Please help me to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restful API docs are at `http://your-alfresco-server:8080/alfresco/service/index/uri/api/upload`.